# Can zRSSFeed handle HTTPS RSS Feed from SharePoint?

Tags: jquery, rss

I'm working on an internal website for my organization. The Company uses SharePoint to allow orgs to create their own blogs. I created a blog (in addition to a website for my org). I am now trying to use zRSSFeed to feed the blog onto the front page. zRSSFeed works with other RSS feeds but not for this SharePoint RSS feed.

The SharePoint feed URL contains `HTTPS`. I believe this is the problem. zRSSFeed documentation says to change the `jquery.zrssfeed.js` file SLL setting to true. I did this but I still cannot get my blog to feed into the front page.

Is SharePoints HTTPS rss URL causing this? How can I fix this?